# How to sum all the numbers under the same name? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to be able to create a cell that can **add numbers that are found below a specific text**.

In the image below there is an image with the basic draft for the idea, however the idea is not to add manually selected cells, as if I add a lot of new cells I would have to manually add them to the addition `(=H12+H14+H16)`.
By making it so it adds all the things below a specific line of text, even when I add more of this cells, the addition will be made automatically without the need of adding the cells individually to the addition.

Of course if this type of 'cell detection' is possible this could make for a lot of more complex equations that usually need manual input to be done automatically as soon as it is added.

I imagine the code looking something like this:`SUMiIF cell untop = "sales"`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
=SUMIF(A2:A,"="&"sales", OFFSET(A2:A,1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Very smart solution, worked wonders. It is also really nice that this can be done with horizontally as well by changing the offset, thank you very much!

Comment: Of course thank you for letting me know, I will do so.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a addition and a subtraction to that addition using the same technique? For example add the sales, then add the loses, and finally subtract the loses from the sales.

Comment: Sure @GabrielVallejo Just use the same logic like: `=SUMIF(...)-SUMIF(...)`. Have [a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrdjb.png).